# Bootstrap 3.0 cause collapse entire code like a sentence, google prittyfy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, prettify

I am using Markdown, google prettify and bootstrap then result comes in single line like this

```
Create Proc log AS Begin Try Select 10 / 0 End Try Begin Catch EXEC LogErr End Catch
```

Just commented out the "~/Content/bootstrap.css" file in bundling of my mvc application and result comes like this

```
Create Proc log 
AS 
Begin Try 
   Select 10 / 0 
End Try 
Begin Catch 
   EXEC LogErr 
End Catch
```

My entire application is designed by using the bootstrap, so I cannot remove this CSS, Is there any way to use the bootstrap with google prettify and markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, here is the class which was causing it

```
pre code {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Change to

```
pre code {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  /*white-space: pre-wrap;*/
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

white-space: `pre-wrap`; was wrapping the code, might be it can help someone.